# How to Save a Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

As the title says I'm trying to save a `TensorSliceDataset` object to file. Viewing tensorflow's [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) it seems that the `tf.data.Dataset` class has a save function but it is not implemented for `TensorSliceDataset` objects. Pickling also did not work for me.

Example code

```
import tensorflow as tf
t = tf.range(10)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(t)
ds.save()
```

returns error: `AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'save'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Tensorflow `2.10.0`, you can use `tf.data.Dataset.save`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
# 2.10.0

path = '/content/'
t = tf.range(10)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(t)

tf.data.Dataset.save(ds, path)
new_ds = tf.data.Dataset.load(path)
```

Otherwise, use `tf.data.experimental.save` for older versions:

```
import tensorflow as tf

path = '/content/'
t = tf.range(10)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(t)
tf.data.experimental.save(ds, path)
new_ds = tf.data.experimental.load(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `TensorSliceDataset` to numpy array and then save it.

Sample code:

```py
np.save('data.npy', np.array(list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())))
```

Answer (score 1):

It simply saves as text or checkpoints.

Sample:

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()
print(physical_devices)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
BATCH_SIZE = 1
IMG_SIZE = (32, 32)
new_dataset_folder = "F:\\temp\\Python\\excel"

PATH = 'F:\\datasets\\downloads\\cats_name'
train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')

train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir, shuffle=True,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, image_size=IMG_SIZE)
                                                            
class_names = train_dataset.class_names

print( 'class_names: ' + str( class_names ) )
print( train_dataset )

### 1. Save dataset using .save()
path = "F:\\temp\\saved_dataset"
train_dataset.save(
    path, compression=None, shard_func=None, checkpoint_args=None
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Dataset
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = {
    "image" :[],
    "label" : []
}

file_order = 0
for data in train_dataset :
    file_path = new_dataset_folder + "\\" + str(int(data[1][0])) + ".npz"
    dataset["image"].append(file_path)
    dataset["label"].append(str(int(data[1][0])))
    # Save
    encoding = "utf-8"
    with open( new_dataset_folder + "\\" + str(file_order), "wb" ) as f:
        f.write(str(data[0]).encode(encoding))
    
    file_order = file_order + 1

### 2. Save dataset using Panda
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dataset_folder, "train.csv"), index=False)
```