# AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, tensorflow2

```
test_ds.save(path)
```

I want to save the tf.data.Dataset,but get the message "AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'save'"

Answer (score 0):

refer to this answer: [How to Save a Tensorflow Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060508/how-to-save-a-tensorflow-dataset)

found out tf version is 2.8.0 in the runtime environment,using `tf.data.experimental.save` works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

using `test_ds.save(path)` I got new problem,"AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'save'"