# How to save ParallelMapDataset?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have an input dataset (let's name it ds), a function that passes in to encoder (model named `embedder`). I want to make a dataset of encodings and save it to file. What I tried to do:

Converter function:

```
def generate_embedding(image, label, embedder):
  return (embedder(image)[0], label)
```

Converting:

```
embedding_ds = ds.map(lambda image, label: generate_embedding(image, label, embedder), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Saving:

```
embedding_ds.save(path)
```

But I have a problem with `embedding_ds`, it's not `tf.data.Dataset` (which I expected), but `tf.raw_ops.ParallelMapDataset`, which don't have **save** method. Can anybody give an advice?

---

Looks like this problem is present on my tensorflow version (2.9.2) and not present on 2.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe update? In 2.11.0, it works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)

tf.__version__ # 2.11.0

ds = ds.map(lambda e : (e + 3) % 5, num_parallel_calls=3)

ds.save('test') # works
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060508/how-to-save-a-tensorflow-dataset/74065365#74065365 @IvanBudnikov